# How do I re-architect this to make it thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I've inherited an old VB6 DLL to control industrial machinery.  I've converted it to C#.   It works well except for one feature:  the VB6 version supported an "asynchronous" model via a timer that woke up every second to update some machinery and update a big set of data structures and global variables.       It got away with this because VB6 was really single threaded even though it could simulate asynchronous-ness by queing events to execute between subroutine calls or via DoEvent's.

In C# we have real asynchronous processing because the **System.Timers.Timer** I'm using results in a new thread being run.   Unfortunately this means that we get threading collisions as the timer thread tries to manipulate items that are also being touched by the user's application thread.

**Caveat:**  The data being manipulated by the timer thread is large and varied - hundreds of different data structures, variables and flags that are used all over the other DLL calls, so it's not practical to make just a few critical sections to protect it.

Ideally it would be easiest to move the work of the timer code into a call that would run in the application thread and just use the timer to somehow trigger this.   But how?

Our test application for this DLL *happens* to be a WPF program, so potentially we could use some sort of DispatchTimer thread to solve this *in our test case*, but we have no basis to assume that the user's applications are Dispatcher-based, so it's not a universal solution.

Comment: "it's not practical to make just a few critical sections to protect it." Why not? That seems like it wouldn't be any worse than the old implementation where all access was from a single thread. I guess you could implement your own producer/consumer dispatcher -- timer is the producer, consumer is the thread where the actual work is done -- so as to not take a dependency on event dispatching (e.g. WPF or WinForms). But barring a code example illustrating why a single top-level lock is insufficient, it's hard to understand what other alternatives would be better.

Comment: Because there are hundreds of different variables and structures used in myriad ways in the DLL - sometimes used in calculations, sometimes for writing out to files and formatting for display.  The industrial machines this is used for have hundreds of parameters. The DLL itself has about 100 entry points.   So if we had to wrap every bit of code that touched any of these in a critical section it would be a nightmare.  I think it would be easier to keep the code currently in the timer basically intact but find a way to execute it in the application thread.   I just don't know how.

Comment: Without a code example, it's impossible to say what could be added to your app thread to allow the timer to cause something to be invoked there. There are techniques you can use, including using a custom `SynchronizationContext` or just writing your own queue of delegates to invoke. But you would still need for your application thread to be ready to consume something from the queue on a regular basis. Whether that's feasible depends on what else that thread is doing. In any case, you took the time to reimplement the whole thing in C#; why not visit every public member and add synchronization?

Comment: Sorry for the run-on, but: it's also not clear why you need to add the synchronization in the object itself. As long as your application thread has well-defined points of access into the object, you can wrap those with the synchronization, along with the timer access. Again, a good code example would go a long way here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could just just run *all your code* on a single thread (and marshal timer ticks to that thread)?

Comment: @Peter Duniho  Not sure what "object" you're referring to.  There are literally hundreds of objects.   Also, I'd be happy to supply a code example, but of what?  As I explained in my question the timer handler is huge because it manipulates so much data - it's about 1100 lines of source code, and mostly it's either assignment statements or calls to set hardware registers in the external hardware.

Comment: @usr - what do you mean "marshall timer ticks to that thread"?

Comment: Is your app entirely event-driven? Or is there a "main thread" that continually does something? As you mentioned WPF if it appears to be driven only by UI events and timer ticks.

Comment: @usr There is no app -  this is a DLL.     Our test app happens to be a WPF app, but because this is a DLL it could be consumed by anything, including non-event-driven programs.

Answer (score 0):

If the timer does not HAVE to process the data every time it goes off, You could use Monitor.TryEnter(), and just declare a syncing object.  Something like.

```
private readonly object _syncObject = new object();

.....

private void ProcessingMethod(){

    if(Monitor.TryEnter(_syncObject))
    {
       try{
              //do some processing.
       }
       finally{
          Monitor.Exit(_syncObject);
       }
    }          
}
```

If the timer does have to process at each interval, then you would need to go with a `lock` statement.  If its processing a long time, you will need to write logic that prevents the timer from getting backlogged.

Im kind of assuming that the objects being processed were not created in the WPF context, or that for some reason you are not able to pass context to the processing method.

Comment: Keep in mind this was converted from VB6, which is not an object-oriented language.  There are just lots of variables and data structures representing parameters for the equipment.    I could wrap them all in a class and instantiate that class so I have an object.  So then in every entrypoint in the DLL would I grab the synchronization object and release it when I exit?